# Given definition of $\cos$ as in Spivak's Calculus, is there a simpler way to show that $\cos{x}=\cos{(-x)}$ than a proof by cases?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, solution-verification

In Spivak's *Calculus*, $\cos$ is defined by

$$A(\cos{x})=\frac{x}{2}$$

if $0\leq x\leq \pi$, where $A(x)=\frac{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}{2}+\int_x^1 \sqrt{1-t^2}dt$ is the function giving the area of a sector of the unit circle starting at $(0,1)$ going counterclockwise.

[image]

If $\pi\leq x\leq 2\pi$ then $\cos{x}$ is defined

$$\cos{x}=\cos{(2\pi-x)}$$

and if $x=2\pi k+x'$ for $x'\in [0,2\pi]$ then $\cos{x}$ is defined

$$\cos{x}=\cos{x'}$$

My question is: how do we show that $\cos{x}=\cos{(-x)}$?

I think I found a way, but it seems quite complicated, and I wonder if there is a simpler way.

Here is what I did

We need to consider three cases for $\cos{(-x)}$.

**Case 1:** $0\leq-x\leq \pi$. Then

$$-\pi\leq x\leq 0 \implies \pi\leq x+2\pi\leq 2\pi$$

$$\cos{x}=\cos{(2\pi\cdot(-1)+x+2\pi)}=\cos{(x+2\pi)}=\cos{(2\pi-x-2\pi)}=\cos{(-x)}$$

**Case 2:** $\pi\leq  -x\leq 2\pi$. Then

$$-2\pi\leq x\leq -\pi \implies 0\leq x+2\pi\leq \pi$$

$$\implies \cos{x}=\cos{(2\pi(-1)+x+2\pi)}=\cos{(x+2\pi)}$$

But we also have $\cos{(-x)}=\cos{(2\pi+x)}$, from the original definition of $\cos$.

Therefore, $\cos{x}=\cos{(-x)}$.

**Case 3:** $-x=2\pi k+x', x'\in [0,2\pi]$

$$\cos{(-x)}=\cos{(x')}=\cos{(-x')}=\cos{(-x'-2\pi k)}=\cos{x}$$

Therefore, in all possible cases, we have

$$\cos{x}=\cos{(-x)}$$

Comment: $\cos(t)$ is the $x$ coordinate at $t$ radians. $\cos(-t)$ is the $x$ coordinate at $-t$ radians. Let $f(t)$ be the point on the circle at $t$ radians. It suffices to show that $f(-t) = \overline{f(t)}$, where $\overline{}$ is reflection across the y axis. This can be proven using the well known result $f(t) = e^{it} = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\frac{i^n}{n!} t^n$.

Comment: Unless I am missing something, shouldn't the formula be:
$$A(\cos x) = \frac{|x|}{2} $$
You are dealing with areas after all :). From here it should be clear that $A(\cos(-x)) = A(\cos x)$. But I'm not sure of how to proceed from here.

Comment: @Gregory you are missing $0\leq x\leq \pi$.

Comment: I don't understand what question you are asking.

Comment: @SuzuHirose is took me a long time to prove that $\cos{x}=\cos{-x}$ using the proof by cases I showed above (it also took me a long time to prove $\sin{x}=-\sin{(-x)}$. My question is if there is a simpler way to prove such simple identities.

Comment: @SuzuHirose I don't think so. That function $A(x)$ is not defined when $x > 1$.

Comment: @Gregory $A(\cos(x))=x/2$, it might be less confusing if it didn't use $x$ for two different things.

Comment: @Gregory for $0\leq x\leq\pi$, $\cos x$ is defined as as the function such that $A(\cos{x})=\frac{x}{2}$. $A$ on the other hand is the function defined above in the main text but for $-1\leq x\leq 1$. Thus the image of $\cos$ must be $[-1,1]$. Note also that $A(-1)=\pi/2$ and $A(1)=0$, and $A$ is continuous, so by the IVT, $A$ takes on all values between $0$ and $\pi/2$ on the interval between $-1$ and $1$.