# How do we show that $\sin{x}$ is in fact equal to the infinite series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

Taylor's Theorem tell us that (given some assumptions) if we write a function $f(x)$ as the sum of a Taylor polynomial and a remainder term, the remainder term has a specific form

$$R_{n,a}(x)=\frac{f^{(n+1)}(t)}{(n+1)!}(x-a)^{n+1}$$

where $t \in (a,x)$.

Let $f(x)=\sin{x}$.

If we let $a=0$ and write out the remainder term and estimate it we can show that the sequence of remainders converges to $0$.

My question is: how do we get from the theory above to showing that in fact $\sin{x}$ equals the associated infinite Maclaurin series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$?

The fact that the remainders converge to $0$ seems to mean that if we consider the sequence of Taylor polynomials, the infinite series of their partial sums is at least pointwise convergent to $\sin{x}$.

If we can show that this infinite series is uniformly convergent, then we are saying that

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} P_{n,a}(x)=f(x), \text{ for all } x$$

This seems to be the answer to my question. Is it?

We would then write

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} P_{n,0}(x)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sin{x}+\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} R_{n,0}(x)=\sin{x}$$

Ie

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}=\sin{x}$$

**But how do we show this uniform convergence?**

I just noticed that if we don't assume $a=0$, then I am not sure what happens.

$\sin{x}$ doesn't seem to be the infinite series of partial sums of Taylor polynomials at some $a\neq 0$.

Comment: What is your definition of the sine function? I've seen courses where the definition itself is the expansion, so it's worth clarifying.

Comment: I am following Spivak's Calculus. Sine was defined in terms of cosine, which was defined as the unique number in $[-1,1]$ such that $A(\cos{x})=\frac{x}{2}$, where $A(x)$ is the area of a piece of a unit circle formed by the x-axis, the circle and the line from the origin to $(x,\sqrt{1-x^2})$.  This is what I mean: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4496149/given-definition-of-cos-as-in-spivaks-calculus-is-there-a-simpler-way-to-sh

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I am using as an example the sine function, but the crux of my question is how do we go from knowing about concepts like Taylor's Theorem, what a sequence and infinite series are, what uniform and pointwise converge are, to being able to state that a function is equal to its associated infinite series representation. What is the theorem in between that allows us to do this?

Comment: @evianpring Not sure what you mean. If you mean that a function is always equal to its Taylor series, it's actually [not true](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function).

Comment: Since the remainder tends to zero, you get pointwise convergence, so the infinite series represents the sine function at each $x$. The remainders tend to zero uniformly in each bounded interval, and that is the best you can say- the convergence is not uniform on the whole line.

Comment: The series is NOT uniformly convergent to $\sin x$ on all of $\Bbb R$. The sum of the first $n$ terms is a non-constant polynomial $P_n(x),$ so $|P_n(x)|\to\infty$ as $x\to\infty .$ So there exists $x_n$ such that $|P_n(x_n)|>42.$ But $|\sin x_n|\le 1.$ So $|P_n(x_n)-\sin x_n|> 41.$

Comment: You don't need uniform convergence to say $\lim P_{n,a}(x) = f(x)$, pointwise convergence is enough.